# get min and max for a column plus all row data

Tags: mysql, group-by

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    users_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL,
    password CHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( users_id )
);

CREATE TABLE games (
    games_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    locations_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (games_id )
);

CREATE TABLE games_users (
    users_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    games_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    score MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    created DATETIME NOT NULL,
    last_updated DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( games_id, users_id )
);
```

With the above tables, each game is between 2 users, so games_users has 2 rows for each game, one for each player, the winner will have the highest score (yes really!).

I want a single row per game, I can get the winning and losing score (using the query below), but i also need to know the winner's and loser's id's.

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    min(score) as loser, 
    max(score) as winner 
FROM games
LEFT JOIN 
    games_members 
ON 
    games_members.games_id = games.games_id
GROUP BY 
    games_members.games_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self join.
Names of columns can be chosen in a better way, if draws are possible.

```
select
    gu1.games_id,
    winner.users_id 'id of the winner',
    gu1.score 'score of the winner',
    looser.users_id 'id of the looser'
    gu2.score 'score of the looser'
from games_users gu1
join games_users gu2 on gu1.games_id = gu2.games_id
join users winner on gu1.users_id = winner.users_is
join users looser on gu2.users_id = looser.users_is
where 1=1
and gu1.score >= gu2.score
and gu1.users_id != gu2.users_id
group by gu1.games_id
```